Can you always split a positive definite Hermitian matrix into blocks based on eigenvalues?
Given a positive-definite, symmetric matrix $M$, and some number $\lambda>0$, can you split it into a block matrix
$$M =\begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ B' & C\end{bmatrix}$$
such that the eigenvalues of $A$ are greater than $\lambda$ and that of $C$ are less than $\lambda$, after possibly changing the indexing of rows and columns.
EDIT: Assume $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $M$.

No. E.g. let $M=\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&1}$. Its two eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\approx 2.618$ and $\lambda_2=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\approx 0.382$. Now let $2<\lambda<\lambda_1$. None of the diagonal elements of $M$ is greater than $\lambda$.

What if you choose $\lambda$ to be an eigenvalue? Then I guess the 2×2 examples will bot work.

@MathewGeorge None of the diagonal elements is greater than $\lambda$ if you choose $\lambda=\lambda_1$.

Yes, but that would be a trivial splitting. In general, largest eigenvalue is greater than any eigenvalue of any principal submatrix. If you wish exclude that case, and take some other non-extreme eigenvalue. I think the answer is still no, but would like to see a counterexample.
